# What happens if you go into the void in the loves and hugs April fools update in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know It has been more than a year, but I was just wondering what would happen

Comment: I just tested it and you do gain love points, but very slowly.

Answer (score 1):

I was just about to do hacky stuff with the launcher to get the version back (it's not in the list), but it's actually already in the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/15w14a#Gameplay) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=15w14a&oldid=1192551)):

> the player is unable to die, including from /kill and the Void

So I'm pretty sure that you would just keep collecting love points. Now that I think about it, that would actually probably be the most efficient way to get to [Minescreeper](https://minecraft.wiki/w/15w14a#Gameplay) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=15w14a&oldid=1192551)): Open to LAN with cheats, do `/fill ~ 0 ~ ~ ~ ~ air` and you should be there pretty quickly.

Comment: Btw, I did try this much later and apparently you get very little hearts from the void for whatever reason. It did bring me to Minescreeper after about 20 minutes, but it was very glitchy.